# Popover shown from inputAccessoryView has wrong rotation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, ios

Does anybody know why a `UIPopover` or `UIActionSheet` presented from a `UIBarButtonItem` in a toolbar in the `inputAccessoryView` doesn't rotate along with all the other view controllers?

The steps to reproduce this are:

1. In an Xcode iPad project, add a `UILabel` editable text field in IB.
2. Also in IB, add a `UIToolbar` with a `UIBarButtonItem`.
3. In code, set the text field's `inputAccessoryView` to the toolbar.
4. Send the `becomeFirstResponder` message to the text field.
5. Present an action sheet from the toolbar button item using `[actionSheet showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];`

You just need to rotate your iPad to any orientation other than Portrait, and then present the popover to see it happen. If you rotate it while the popover is open, the popover rotates as well so it's in the same weird orientation relative to the rest of the app.

[image]
<sub>(source: [tumblr.com](http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_l6k9psjave1qzbd4bo1_500.png))</sub>

**Update 2010-08-04** Turns out all popovers and action sheets shown from a item in a toolbar that's an input accessory view (for the keyboard) have this issue. I have submitted a Radar to Apple with Bug ID# 8272121.

Comment: Your screenshot has gone 403. I suggest using imgur instead.

Comment: I had it on TwitPic which uses Amazon S3 apparently. It's now on a tumblr.com server.

Comment: How did you cope with the issue then?

Comment: I moved the "Add Picture" button to the form's toolbar at the top, instead of the keyboard's accessory view. The Radar was marked as a duplicate so I have no idea what happened to it.